# How to create snippets for rails view in atom text editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor

I want to add these rails views snippets in atom text editor. But I don't know how to do it. Can anyone provide some suggestion. I have used html.erb

#### `<%= %>`

#### `<% %>`

This is what I have but I can't figure out the source type

```
'.source.html.erb':
 'embed =':
'prefix':'='
'body':"""
  <%= $1 %>
"""

'.source.html.erb':
 'embed':
'prefix':'-'
'body':"""
  <% $1 %>
"""
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this snippet on my `snippets.cson` in Atom and work fine, You can try it.

```
'.html':
  'Ruby line':
    'prefix': '%'
    'body': '<%= $1 %>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'.text.html.erb':
  'Hello':
    'prefix': 'hi'
    'body': '<%= "Hello" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Click on Atom in the main menu, then click on snippets. This is the file where you can create custom snippets. For your snippet, you can enter this code:

```
'erb':
    'prefix': 'erb'
    'body': '<%= ${1:object} %>'
```

For more information on creating custom snippets, checkout [Atom.io Snippets](http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/)

Comment: i added the code  **` 'erb':
    'prefix': 'erb'
    'body': '<%= ${1:object} %>'`** to my snippets.cson file but nothing happend when i type erb + Tab key

Comment: Did you restart atom?